# Quick way to modify to multiple filenames in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames

I have files:

1.pgm ... 400.pgm consecutive numbers from 1 to 400 all in same format.

I want to copy them into:

401.pgm ... 800.pgm, it's basicaly because I need more input data

I'm wondering if there's any quick way to do this in Linux?

Comment: A simple [shell script](http://freeos.com/guides/lsst/) should suffice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file have this structure, then simply:

```
for file in *.pgm ; do
   num=${file%%.pgm}
   newnum=$(( $num + 400 ))  #more portable than 'let', thx to @user2719058 for the reminder!
   echo mv "${file}" "${newnum}.pgm"
done
```

and take out the `echo` once you're confident that this does what you want...

Comment: Note that `let` is bash-specific.

Comment: @user2719058 thanks, I thought it was more portable than $((...)), and it turns out it's the opposite! thanks indeed.

Comment: @user2719058: actually, it's not bash specific... I'll provide both ways anyway.

Comment: well, AFAIK `let` stems from the korn shell, and bash and zsh support it. So, it's not strictly bash-specific, but you can't expect it to be present in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

With `rename(1)`:

```
rename 's/(\d+)/400+$1/e' *.pgm
```

That's a separate program, though. A slightly less elegant way in pure bash is

```
for f in *.pgm; do mv $f $((400+${f//[!0-9]/})).pgm; done
```